# How to fix brown map with a logo of google using the (react-native-maps)

Tags: android, google-maps, react-native

I'm new developing react-native, I have modules of tracking all the users based on there location (lat and long) now. I started installing the npm install react-native-maps --save, well the installation is good, now I started Build configuration on Android

Note:I use my mobile phone to run the application

Question:

1.Is this working in all devices?

2.Is it issue on API key?

3.Is it problem version of react-native-maps?

I just follow the configuration in the documentation.
https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/installation.md

Now i started creating my credentials in the

https://console.cloud.google.com

[image: Credential]

Now in my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

package="com.tracker">

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>

<application
  android:name=".MainApplication"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
  android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
  android:allowBackup="false"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
  <activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
  </activity>
  <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
   <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="Keep Secret first"/>
</application>
```

In my app.js

**IMPORT**

```
import MapView from 'react-native-maps';
```

**RETURN**

```
<View style={styles.container}>
    <MapView style = {styles.mapcontainer}
      showsUserLocation={true}
      showsMyLocationButton={false}
      zoomEnabled = {true}
      initialRegion={{
        latitude: 37.78825,
        longitude: -122.4324,
        latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
        longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
      }} >
    </MapView>
  </View>
```

**CSS**

```
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  mapcontainer: {
    flex: 1,
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject
  },
 });
```

Now the result is this,
[image: Result]

The debugger look like this

[image: Debugger]

I hope someone can help me with the problem. Thanks

Logcat
[image: Logcat]

Comment: Make sure you keep that meta-deta in `AndroidManifest` file between the `<application>` tag. This happened to me because I had issues with the google maps api key.

Comment: @AtinSingh yah surely. wait i put my minfest

Comment: Please see update ..

Comment: You created an API key of Maps SDK for android, right?

Comment: yes i create for the credentials for the google apps

Comment: Have a look at logcat of the Android phone. Usually the maps API gives you some feedback.

Comment: I will show you the debugger UI. in the console

Comment: I really mean the Android Logcat. Not the RN logging.

Comment: @Christopher where do i find the android logcat in the mobile phone?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat

Comment: Can you see the new update christopher if that is the logcat?

Answer (score 0):

I think this issue because of SHA1 please add package name and SHA1 key on google api console.

SHA1 key generate from android studio.[Get Key from here....](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ladBH.png)

[Add Package name and SHA 1 key here....](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kd5Is.png)